# How to place a fixed button in the upper right in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have been unable to get this button to go into the far upper right corner, and it is also throwing off the alignment of my heading.  I've tried several things but I am stuck.

```
<head>      
  <style>
      .myButton {
      padding: 0px;
      display:block;
      float:right;
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
      text-align:center;
    }

    </style>
    <a href="Login Page.html" class="myButton">Username</a>
    <h1 style="font-size:50px;">Leaderboard</h1>
</head>
```

Comment: Add to `h1` `float:left`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.myButton {
      padding: 0px;
      display:block;
      position:fixed;
      top:2x;
      right:0px;
      background-color: green;
      color: white;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

change top and right properties to adjust.

Comment: Using this, and setting top to 0px instead of 2px gave me exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: good job. welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a href="Login Page.html" class="myButton fixed to-top-right">Username</a>
```

---

CSS:

```
.myButton {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}

.fixed {
    display: fixed;
}

.fixed.to-top-right {
    left: unset;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to align a object in css without use of position fixed or absolute is to use diplay flex

**Note that this not fixed**

```css
header{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    }
header a{
    margin-left: auto;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#">btn</a>
</header>
```

**This is fixed**

```css
  header a{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#">btn</a>
</header>
```